# C++ Encrypting/Decrypting using transposition cipher

Tags: c++, encryption

I am writing a program for my CS2400 class as homework where we are to either encrypt a message, decrypt a message, or let the user quit.

I began by setting up the functions without writing too much in the definitions.

This is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void encryption (char message[]);//prototype
void decryption (char message[]);//prototype

int main(){
    int ans=0;
    char message[100];

    while (ans!=3){
        cout << "1. Encrypt a message.\n2. Decrypt a message.\n3. Quit\n";
        cin >> ans;

        if (ans==1){
            encryption (message);
        }

        if (ans==2){
            decryption (message);
        }

        if (ans==3){
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void encryption (char message[]){
    int count=0;
    cout << "Please enter a message to be encrypted:\n\n";
    cin.get(message[count]);

    while (message[count]!='\n'){
        count++;
        cin.get(message[count]);
    }

}

void decryption (char message[]){
    int count=0;
    cout << "Please enter a message to be decrypted:\n\n";
    cin.get(message[count]);

    while (message[count]!='\n'){
        count++;
        cin.get(message[count]);
    }

}
```

When run, it lets me choose an option of the three, but when choosing encrypt or decrypt, it prints the statement asking for input then makes me choose again without giving me a chance to input anything.

Any ideas on why it wont give me a chance to input anything?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cin >> ans` does *not* consume the Enter keypress (newline). So when you proceed to calling `cin.get()`, the first character returned is the Enter keypress from the previous line.

A better idea is to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for *all* user input. Doing that will avoid this problem.

Comment: So I should replace cin >> ans with std::getline(ans)?

Comment: @BigSmooth: Yes, that's the idea. `std::getline()` takes two parameters, not one, and it always gives you a string back. So if you are expecting integer input (such as for your menu selection), you will then have to convert the string to an integer with [`std::stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cin.ignore()` after `cin>>ans`